# Using put in callback

Tags: react-native, redux-saga

i'm using react-native with saga, and i want to throw an alert on request succeeded. I want to know how to put an action in the alert callback, and if there is a better way to do this.

```
function* userRequest(action) {
    try {
        const user = yield call(Api.post, Routes.REQUEST_USER, params);
        yield put({type: types.REQUEST_OK, user: user});
    } catch(e) {
        yield put({type: types.REQUEST_FAILED, user: user});
    }
}

function* requestOk(action) {
    Alert.alert(
        'User',
        'User request ok!',
        [
            //I know this is wrong
            {text: 'OK', onPress: () => yield put({type: types.NAVIGATION_BACK})},
        ],
        { cancelable: false }
    )
}

function* userSaga() {
    yield takeEvery(types.USER_REQUEST, userRequest);
    yield takeEvery(types.REQUEST_OK, requestOk);
}
```

Thanks you!

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I also need to do this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can write the `Alert.alert()` method inside of a promise and resolve or reject based on which option the user select.

Create the alert inside a Promise

```
function showAlert(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Alert.alert(
      'User',
      'User request ok!',
      [
        {text: 'OK', onPress: () => resolve('confirmed') },
        {text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => reject('canceled')}
      ],
      { cancelable: false }
    )
  })
}
```

In your generator...

```
function* requestOK(){
   try{
     const confirm = yield call(showAlert);

     //promise resolved, user confirmed
     yield put({type: types.NAVIGATION_BACK});

   }catch(error){
      //user selected cancel
   }
}
```

https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/508#issuecomment-243336353

Answer (score 1):

You can use eventChannel

```
function alert(){
  return eventChannel(emitter => {
    Alert.alert(
      'User',
      'User request ok!',
      [
        {text: 'OK', onPress: () => emitter('OK')},
      ],
      { cancelable: false }
    )
  })
}

function* saga(){
  yield takeEvery(types.REQUEST_OK, function*(){
    const channel = yield alert()
    // while(true){
    const button = yield take(channel)
    yield put({type: types.NAVIGATION_BACK})
    // }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`takeEvery` takes optional arguments, so I've found the best way to do this is to pass your store through to the saga and then use `store.dispatch` to fire your action:

```
import {createStore} from 'redux';
const store = createStore(...)  // you'll already have this somewhere

---

function* userSaga(store) {
  yield takeEvery(types.REQUEST_OK, requestOk, store);

---

function* requestOk(store, action) {  // store is now the first arg
  Alert.alert(
    'User',
    'User request ok!',
    [
        {text: 'OK', onPress: () => store.dispatch({type: types.NAVIGATION_BACK})},
    ],
    { cancelable: false }
  )
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is the correct solution. Is there any other way to use put in a callback that you found?

Comment: Directly call `store.dispatch` in saga seems too violent